# Filter items according to the values in the class

Tags: jquery

I'm having difficulty filtering items according to the values that are in the item class. Items must always be ordered from the highest value to the lowest.

Example Item view: `<div id="mt-138" class="id[138] rating[8.1] views[350] item">item1</div>`

```
id = Last added Item
rating = Top Rated Item
views = Most Viewd Items
```

I am using a simple dropdown menu:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Filter
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a id="last-added" href="#">Last added</a></li>
    <li><a id="top-rated" href="#">Top rated</a></li>
    <li><a id="most-viewed" href="#">Most viewed</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uj95oe7b/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
        $(function () {
            $('.dropdown-menu a').click(function () {
                var triggerId = $(this).attr('id');
                $('.item').detach().sort(function (thisElement, otherElement) {
                    var pattern = '\\[(\\d+(\\.\\d+)*)\\]';
                    switch(triggerId)
                    {
                        case 'last-added':
                            pattern = 'id' + pattern;
                            break;
                        case 'top-rated':
                            pattern = 'rating' + pattern;
                            break;
                        case 'most-viewed':
                            pattern = 'views' + pattern;
                            break;
                    }
                    var regex = new RegExp(pattern);
                    var thisValue = regex.exec($(thisElement).attr('class'))[1];
                    var otherValue = regex.exec($(otherElement).attr('class'))[1];
                    return otherValue - thisValue;
                }).appendTo('body');
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Filter
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a id="last-added" href="#">Last added</a></li>
            <li><a id="top-rated" href="#">Top rated</a></li>
            <li><a id="most-viewed" href="#">Most viewed</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="mt-138" class="id[138] rating[8.1] views[50] item">item1</div>
    <div id="mt-139" class="id[139] rating[8] views[350] item">item2</div>
    <div id="mt-140" class="id[140] rating[7.9] views[35] item">item3</div>
```